# How does multiclassing affect the damage scaling of Hexblade's curse?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, proficiency, hexblade

So,I am playing a multiclass character with level 14 in fighter and level 1 in Warlock. Now Hexblade's curse damage depends on player's proficiency bonus.My level 15 character's proficiency bonus is +5 but a level1 warlock's proficiency bonus is +2. So, which proficiency bonus should I add as hexblade's curse damage?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!